# How to grab a value inside nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble trying to grab a certain value out of this dictionary/list mess..  Trying to print TARGET|CHANGE

```
example = [{'add_app_key_to_env': {'app': '"fdsgsd"',
                         'commit_message': '"Add key dsfgfd to app fdsgsd"',
                         'ecntype': '"core"',
                         'env': '"{{ target_env }}"',
                         'key': '"dsfgfd"',
                         'password': '"{{ password }}"',
                         'username': '"{{ username }}"',
                         'value': '"{{ sdfgd }}"'},
  'name': '"[Step 1] Add key dsfgfd to app fdsgsd"',
  'register': '"est1"',
  'when': 'TEST1|CHANGED OR TEST2|CHANGED '},
 {'name': '"[Step 2] Trigger siteops envkeys regeneration"',
  'trigger_tc_build': {'build_id': 'bt15300',
                       'password': '"{{ AD_PASSWORD }}"',
                       'username': '"{{ AD_USER }}"',
                       'wait_for_completion': '"yes"'},
  'when': 'TARGET|CHANGE '},
 {'add_app_key_to_env': {'app': '"sdfg"',
                         'commit_message': '"Add key hdfgh to app sdfg"',
                         'ecntype': '"core"',
                         'env': '"{{ target_env }}"',
                         'key': '"hdfgh"',
                         'password': '"{{ password }}"',
                         'username': '"{{ username }}"',
                         'value': '"{{ dfgh }}"'},
  'name': 'Add key hdfgh to app sdfg',
  'register': '"test2"'}]
```

currently when I print `example[-0]['when']`

I get `TEST1|CHANGE OR TEST2|CHANGE`.  The problem is I'm trying to get `TARGET|CHANGE`.  I am confused about how to get the target change because they appear to both have the same "when" key.

Comment: `example[1]['when']`

Comment: Try to print the dictionary with `pprint`. Makes more sense.

Comment: example[1]['when'] gives me index error: list out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a list of three separate dictionaries.

```
you_want = example[1]

In [71]: you_want
Out[71]: 
{'name': '"[Step 2] Trigger siteops envkeys regeneration"',
 'trigger_tc_build': {'build_id': 'bt15300',
 'password': '"{{ AD_PASSWORD }}"',
 'username': '"{{ AD_USER }}"',
 'wait_for_completion': '"yes"'},
 'when': 'TARGET|CHANGE '}

In [72]: you_want.get('when')
Out[72]: 'TARGET|CHANGE '
```